# What is the term for 'clean fracture vector'?

Tags: forces, material-science, structure-formation, adhesion

Today I observed a builder demolishing a wall in a house. He knew how to hit it in exactly the right place, with the right amount of force, for it to cleanly break into three smaller pieces - along fault lines.

Today I observed a household member crack a boiled egg with a single, perfectly aligned whack of a knife handle, breaking the shell cleanly into to separate pieces.

There must be a term for this 'clean fracture vector'.

My question is: **What is the term for 'clean fracture vector'?**

Comment: In relation to eggs you can buy "egg clackers" which use this effect. I'm not saying "clack" is the scientific term, you understand.

Comment: I don't know if one vector alone is enough information? Maybe one Vector + one Point?